# pagination; Results from multiple models

Tags: cakephp

I have built a cake model that, when searched, needs to return paginated results that exclude some items based on data in another model.

I have a model called Box and a model called Item.

Each box can have 0 or more items, but I only want the boxes with 1 or more items with the category of Fruit to appear in a pagination result.

The Box model has a 'hasMany' association with the Item model.

The Item model has a field called 'is_friut'.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 1):

This will make an inner join between the tables, only when the item is_fruit.

```
public $paginate = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'items',
            'alias' => 'ItemJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'ItemJoin.is_fruit' => 1
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks very close. However, the 'is_fruit' flag is in the Item model, not the Box model.

Comment: Oh, oops. You would a join in that case. I'll fix my response shortly.